# How to navigate to another activity based on viewmodel's logic, with view binding / MVVM?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I have:

- MainActivity
- MainFragment
- MainViewModel
- SecondActivity
- ThirdActivity

I have a button in fragment_main.xml. I can easily pass it android:onClick="navigate" and have the function navigate() in MainActivity create an intent and start SecondActivity like so:

```
    fun navigate(v: View) {
        intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

But what if I want the button to navigate to a different activity (ThirdActivity) if a bool is true?

This is what I've tried, but the binding in the MainActivity doesn't work:

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val navBoolLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun navigate() {
        val boolio = false
        navBoolLiveData.postValue(boolio)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                add<MainFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun navigateObserver() {
// this is never called
        viewModel.navBoolLiveData.observe(this) { boolio ->
            if (!boolio) {
                intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                intent = Intent(this, ThirdActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling I'm going about this all wrong. My binding in MainFragment does work, but I wasn't sure it should even be involved in the navigation logic or actual nav call.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what behavior you're trying to get. LiveData is almost certainly the wrong way to go about initiating navigation. It's for keeping views up to date with the latest data or state, not *events* that should happen once. You'll be fighting all kinds of bugs like multiple copies of the activity being added to the stack if the user rotates the screen while it's navigating.

Comment: In that case, where should the business logic go? I thought it was standard for the view model to handle the logic, and the activity to handle the actions on the view. Maybe I shouldn't be using view binding for navigation at all?

Comment: Not sure I agree with @Tenfour04. LiveData can be utilized for events (Using Google's [SingleLiveEvent](https://abhiappmobiledeveloper.medium.com/android-singleliveevent-of-livedata-for-ui-event-35d0c58512da)) and a navigation can be considered as an event. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335250/call-view-model-method-from-xml-not-invoke-issue-in-android) for binding a View (XML) to a ViewModel

Comment: @gioravered I oversimplified. LiveData can be used, but not in the way shown above. Google has posted follow-up articles on Medium that firmly discredit SingleLiveEvent. You can use a LiveData, by making the type of the LiveData a mutable class where you can modify a property in it to mark it as consumed.

Comment: You haven't called navigateObserver() function in your onCreate().

Comment: I should also mention I was reacting to the code in the answer that's been deleted by the OP. (You could add that to your question.) In it, the click listener of the button was calling `navigateObserver()`. Not a usual way of observing LiveData. The actual desired behavior here is unclear.Currently, that Boolean doesn't represent an event. It represents the current state of how events initiated by the UI should behave.

Comment: I think we need to know what conditions are intended to change this Boolean value and whether it should have a default behavior. Right now, you just set it to false always.

Comment: from where are you calling `navigateObserver()` ? Becauseee you need to call that function atleast once to start observing live data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing call to `navigateObserver()` in your `onCreate()`. Also, to use LiveData for events such as navigation, you should reset the state after the change is consumed. i.e. after you are done navigating. This is help in preventing bugs. Below is an example:

1. Create a LiveData for navigation event in your ViewModel

   ```
   val navigationEvent = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
   ```
2. Create a fun to reset the state of event, after you navigated

   ```
   fun navigationEventComplete() {
        navigationEvent.value = false
   }
   ```
3. Observe the event in your fragment

   ```
   viewModel.navigationEvent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it == true) {
                navigate()
                // after navigation reset the state, to signal you are done navigating
                viewModel.navigationEventComplete()
            }
        })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SingleLiveEvent](https://abhiappmobiledeveloper.medium.com/android-singleliveevent-of-livedata-for-ui-event-35d0c58512da) to avoid get previous emits.
after that call navigateObserver() in onCreate method to start observing